# Option tree flexslider admin panel

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, flexslider

I 'm developing a wordpress theme. I have just integrate flexslider.
This is my settings default :

```js
$.flexslider.defaults = {
    namespace: "flex-",             //{NEW} String: Prefix string attached to the class of every element generated by the plugin
    selector: ".slides > li",       //{NEW} Selector: Must match a simple pattern. '{container} > {slide}' -- Ignore pattern at your own peril
    animation: "fade",              //String: Select your animation type, "fade" or "slide"
    easing: "swing",                //{NEW} String: Determines the easing method used in jQuery transitions. jQuery easing plugin is supported!
    direction: "horizontal",        //String: Select the sliding direction, "horizontal" or "vertical"
    reverse: false,                 //{NEW} Boolean: Reverse the animation direction
    animationLoop: "enable_animation_slider",            //Boolean: Should the animation loop? If false, directionNav will received "disable" classes at either end
    smoothHeight: false,            //{NEW} Boolean: Allow height of the slider to animate smoothly in horizontal mode
    startAt: 0,                     //Integer: The slide that the slider should start on. Array notation (0 = first slide)
    slideshow: true,                //Boolean: Animate slider automatically
    slideshowSpeed: 7000,           //Integer: Set the speed of the slideshow cycling, in milliseconds
    animationSpeed: 600,            //Integer: Set the speed of animations, in milliseconds
    initDelay: 0,                   //{NEW} Integer: Set an initialization delay, in milliseconds
    randomize: false,               //Boolean: Randomize slide order
    thumbCaptions: false,
```

In my theme-options.php i have create this :

```html
 /* Slider Settings */
      array(
        'label'       => 'Enable animation loop Slider',
        'id'          => 'enable_animation_slider',
        'type'        => 'checkbox',
        'desc'        => 'Check if you want to disable loop',
        'choices'     => array(
          array(
            'label'       => 'false',
            'value'       => 'false'
          )
        ),
        'std'         => 'false',
        'rows'        => '',
        'post_type'   => '',
        'taxonomy'    => '',
        'class'       => '',
        'section'     => 'slider_default'
      ),
```

My problem is flexslider do not grab id enable_animation_slider and settings admin panel not work.